# How to put Weekdays and Weekends on the x-axis of a graph - Excel

Tags: excel, graph, axis, weekday, weekend

I have a hourly data of a entire week in excel, and I want to plot  it! 
But when I do so, in the x-axis appears the hours of the week (i.e, from 1 to 168), as it was expected. But I would prefer that it would just appear the days of the week, i.e., instead of the first 24h, it would appear just 'Monday'.

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extra column which calculates the weekday from the datetime value. Just put this calculated weekday in one column next to the hourly data, and select this column as the x-axis.